# "You and I" or "you and me"

Tags: pronouns, nouns, dummy-pronouns

"You and I" is supposed to be used in the subject of the sentence.

If the sentence starts with "It's you and I", does that mean it's supposed to be "you and me" because "It" is the subject and "you and (I/me)" is the object?

Answer (score 1):

The kind of noun phrase following copular verbs like "be" and "become" is NOT the verb's object. It is called the subject complement.

In natural English, "you and me" rather than "you and I" is used after the verb "be," not because it is an object but because people normally use "it's me," etc. as a fixed construction. This is an area of English grammar that sets descriptive grammarians apart from prescriptive grammarians.